# How to get POST data merged with existing instance data in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

A common pattern in `validate` methods is to compare two field values. For example:

```
def validate(self, attrs: typing.Dict[str, typing.Any]) -> typing.Dict[str, typing.Any]:
    end_datetime = attrs.get('end_datetime', self.instance.end_datetime if self.instance else None)
    if not end_datetime:
        return attrs

    if end_datetime < attrs.get('start_datetime', self.instance.start_datetime if self.instance else None):
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'end_datetime': 'This value cannot be before the start datetime'})

    return attrs
```

I'm currently using a helper method developed by a colleague to replace the `attrs.get` calls above with `self._get_input_or_instance_attribute(attrs, 'field_name')`, which basically does the same thing: get the `attrs` entry with a specific name if it exists, or else, if we're updating an existing instance, get its current value. **Is there a better way to do this,** such as a built-in property or method to get the POST/PUT/PATCH data merged with existing instance data, when applicable?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant updating the instance with the new request data, then no. It isn't (and probably shouldn't) be done before validation else there maybe errors as the validity of the data is not yet confirmed. The update should only come after the validation. 
For the few cases where you have to compare 2 fields in the request data or fall back to the existing instance data, the approach you took is good. If you have many of such cases, then using a method for it like your colleague already does, is a good idea